# What is wrong with this P argument

Tags: data-science, computer-science, polynomial-math, np, computation

My teacher made this argument and asked us what could be wrong with it.

for an array A of n distinct numbers. Since there are n! permutations of A,
we cannot check for each permutation whether it is sorted, in a total time which
is polynomial in n. Therefore, sorting A cannot be in P.

my friend thought that it just should be : therefore sorting a cannot be in NP.
Is that it or are we thinking to easily about it?

Comment: This question is probably more related to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this argument is that it fails to adequately specify the exact problem.

Sorting can be linear-time (O(n)) in the number of elements to sort, if you're sorting a large list of integers drawn from a small pool (counting sort, radix sort).

Sorting can be linearithmic-time (O(nlogn)) in the number of elements to sort, if you're sorting a list of arbitrary things which are all totally ordered according to some ordering relation (e.g., less than or equal to on the integers).

Sorting based on a partial order (e.g. topological sorting) must be analyzed in yet another way.

We can imagine a problem like sorting whereby the sortedness of a list cannot be determined by comparing adjacent entries only. In the extreme case, sortedness (according to what we are considering to be sorting) might only be verifiable by checking the entire list. If our kind of sorting is designed so as to guarantee there is exactly one sorted permutation of any given list, the time complexity is factorial-time (O(n!)) and the problem is not in P.

That's the real problem with this argument. If your professor is assuming that "sorting" refers to sorting integers not in any particular small range, the problem with the argument then is that we do not need to consider all permutations in order to construct the sorted one. If I have a bag with 100 marbles and I ask you to remove three marbles, the time complexity is constant-time; it doesn't matter that there are n(n-1)(n-2)/6 = 161700, or O(n^3), ways in which you can accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is a non-sequitur, the conclusion does not logically follow from the previous steps. Why doesn't it follow? Giving a satisfying answer to that question requires knowing why the person who wrote the argument *thinks* it is correct, and then addressing their misconception. In this case, the person who wrote the argument is your teacher, who *doesn't* think the argument is correct, so there is no misconception to address and hence no completely satisfying answer to the question.

That said, my explanation would be that the argument is wrong because it proposes a specific algorithm for sorting - namely, iterating through all n! permutations and choosing the one which is sorted - and then assumes that the complexity of the problem is the same as the complexity of that algorithm. This is a mistake because the complexity of a problem is defined as the lowest complexity out of *all* algorithms which solve it. The argument only considered one algorithm, and didn't show anything about other algorithms which solve the problem, so it cannot reach a conclusion about the complexity of the problem itself.